# Jquery/JS Make array for jqplot with .each()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqplot

have this problem where I need to make an array like this to use jqplot draw a graph:

```
array = [ ["Nov 24 2014", 3], ["Nov 25 2014", 4], ["Nov 26 2014", 5] ]
```

I have tried the following:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var motivation = [];
 $.each(json, function (i, elem) {
                        var temp = [];
                        temp.push(elem.value1);
                        temp.push(elem.value2);
                        console.log(temp);
                        motivation.push(temp);
                    });
```

The only result I am able to get is an array looking like this.

```
motivation = [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

But I need something that looks like the array in the top.

Anyone?

EDIT:

When I log Temp array I get:

```
   ["Nov 24 2014", 3]
   ["Nov 25 2014", 3]
   ["Nov 26 2014", 4]
```

As I want. 
But when I put them in Motivation array I get

```
  [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
```

It is the right values when I open the arrays, for example the first one:

```
0: Array[2]
   0: "Nov 24 2014"
   1: 3
```

Comment: where is `mot`? I can't see where you declared it.

Comment: one sec, that was a mistake mot = temp. I'm looking for a place to edit the question

Comment: @Mer0 It's under the question tags.

Comment: did you log `temp` or `motivation`? `console.log(temp)` or `console.log(motivation)`?

Comment: both. log(temp) is showing it right, putting [value1, value2] in an array. But when I try to put them together in a final array it makes like a nested one

Comment: [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]] is the same as [ ["Nov 24 2014", 3], ["Nov 25 2014", 4], ["Nov 26 2014", 5] ]. just log 'motivation[0][0]' or `motivation[0][1]`.

Comment: you use `motivation` array in your code, so it's not important what it look likes. you can retrieve it's value just like you expected.

Comment: hmm. So the problem is that I need to convert my Date to something else befor jqplot knows how to render it